# Android Studio: Repository defined in module not respected

Tags: android, module, gradle, crashlytics

I've got a project in Android Studio and I can't quite seem to figure out this gradle issue. My app structure is as follows:
app (module) relies on crashlib (module), crashlib relies on an AAR from an external repository which I have listed in crashlib's gradle file.

The problem is that when I go to compile the app the default repository (https://jcenter.bintray.com/) is used instead of the one defined in crashlib, so the build fails. If I add the repository definition from crashib to the app module then it builds successfully, but it's not ideal. I can also build crashlib successfully on its own.

Here is the crashlib build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.3@aar')
}
```

Any ideas how to get the repository to be used when building the app?

Answer (score 0):

In your buildscript block you should use somenthing like this:

```
   buildscript {
      repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
      }
      dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't seem to make a change, the error is the same. Gradle is still trying to pull from the jcenter repo.

Here's part of the error:
`code`Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.3.
     Searched in the following locations:         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/2.2.3/crashlytics-2.2.3.pom